# Using a background image for a button. How can I resize the button based on the length of the text?

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to learn html and css. I am using a background image for my button. How can I resize the button so all the text fits within it.

Here is my css code

```
#header a{
display: compact;
background: url("images/tab.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
color: #FFFFCC;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0.75em 1em .025em;
background-size: contain;
}
```

Heres the html:

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="">Overview</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">This text is too long</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi! can you provide image if possible what you want to achieve so that i have an idea in helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it is more backwards compatible than using `background-size:cover`.

The HTML:

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="">Short Menu Item</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">Much Longer Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
ul {
    margin-left:0 ;
    padding-left:0 ;
    list-style-type:none ;
}

li {
    margin:12px 0 !important ;
}

a {
    color: #FFFFCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:left ;
    padding:4px ;
    background: url("http://d-grafix.com/textures/2006-07-31/2006-07-31-seamless-grass-9613645-thumb.jpg") ;
}
```

Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kg5D6/1/